# Questions regarding Red-Black Tree Deletion (z has 2 children) (pre-fixDelete)

Tags: c++, data-structures, red-black-tree

Code Source -  https://github.com/Bibeknam/algorithmtutorprograms/blob/master/data-structures/red-black-trees/RedBlackTree.cpp

```
    y = z;
    int y_original_color = y->color;
    if (z->left == TNULL) {
        x = z->right;
        rbTransplant(z, z->right);
    } else if (z->right == TNULL) {
        x = z->left;
        rbTransplant(z, z->left);
    } else {
        y = minimum(z->right);
        y_original_color = y->color;
        x = y->right;                            
        if (y->parent == z) {
            x->parent = y;                       \\ [1] Local Class TNull
        } else {
            rbTransplant(y, y->right);           \\ [2] Losing Y
            y->right = z->right;
            y->right->parent = y;
        }

        rbTransplant(z, y);
        y->left = z->left;
        y->left->parent = y;
        y->color = z->color;                     \\ [3] Need of Recoloring
    }
```

Questions

- 1. Local Class TNull - (In case `y->right` is a `TNull`) Within this class function, TNull is a local pointer simply passed to `x`; isn't changing the `parent` of `x` also change the parent of the local `TNull`?
- 2. Losing Y - This section is meant to be executed in case the minimum in right subtree of `z` is not a direct children. Later it will be placed at `z`'s location. Won't this segment only pivot `y->right / x` until it reaches `z`'s location, instead of `y / minimum`?
- 3. Need of Recoloring - Iirc, recoloring will also happen in the later `fixDelete()` function call, why is this needed?

Please bear with me, I'm slow in this kind of stuff and I'm really at my wits' end. This is the first time I'm asking here. Thank you.

Comment: If I came across something on Github I didn't understand, I would think that my best chances for getting an explanation would be from an inquiry to the Github project directly, instead of asking a question on some other web site where chances are slim that anyone heard of that github project, know what it's all about, how it works, is familiar with the code, and can immediately understand the context and know the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the author has been inactive for a couple of years and issues submitted for the code has been left unresolved for more than a year so I doubt they'll answer. plus, this is a general code for red black trees. I've looked at a psuedocode from another site and its the same, just adapted for c++.

Comment: The other option would simply be to run the code in a debugger and step through the parts that are confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your questions

- Yes that can happen, TNull's parent is set and the authors remark that this is a deliberate design choice which they exploit.
- y is moving to where z is and this just fixes y so its pointers are what z had. s
- No. Essentially when the node to be deleted has 2 children, you find the successor or predecessor node (which has to have 0 or 1 child) and swap the nodes. You then delete the node at the successor or predecessor node position. The predecessor or successor node swapped, preserves the tree ordering. But the important thing is in swapping the nodes, **the colour is not swapped, it must be preserved** so the red-black tree properties are still correct.
  This is what y_original_color is for.

Comment: Finally someone answered! I'll get into it later, it's still 4 in the morning here. Thanks.

Comment: Just a further comment: For deletions of nodes, the RBTree property that can be sabotaged in the black tree path count. Basically all deletions are easy except for deletion of a leaf node (no children) that is black. That is what delete fixup is for. And fixup is a 2-prong strategy: You work your way up the tree towards  the root, looking for a red node among parent, sibling and siblings children. If you find one by rotation and colour flipping, you can restore the deficiency in black node count. If you don't find any red node you make the sibling red and now the problem moves up 1-level

Comment: Wait. I think I'm having a moment of enlightenment.

Comment: Now that I'm think about it, I made my own presumptions about the code, even including functions not visible in it. (1) No part in the code limits the 'TNull' to have varying parent. (2) Its not like 'rbTransplant' deletes 'y', it only bothers with the parents of 'u' and 'v'.

About (3), I still don't understand it. Wow, thanks.